# Can I expose a spark master in Google Dataproc to another service running on Cloud Run?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-dataproc

I have my application deployed as Cloud Run service and one of its features is submitting spark jobs to a spark master using a url in the form of `spark://<spark-master-url>:7077` that can be configured appropriately.

I have successfully setup a spark cluster using Dataproc but apparently the spark master is not publicly exposed and does not have a url like the above that I can use.

Is there a way to expose the spark master to my Cloud Run app so that it can send jobs to it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See if enabling component gateway resolves this issue. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways